# First visible column in datasheet form

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form with datasheet subform.
Is it possible to determine, which column is visible as first in subform after horizontal scrolling?

Tried to compare all properties of subform, subform.form and one of the columns before and after scrolling - no changes in properties.

Comment: The only option I see is using ColumnOrder, ColumnWidth and the ScrollbarPosition (you need the WinAPI for that) to calculate the first visible column yourself. - Quite some effort needed. I've got a sample database at http://codekabinett.com/page.php?Theme=10&Lang=1#SyncScrollBars that could be starting point for retrieving the scrollbar position.

Comment: @PhilS, Thanks for idea and code, I think it will be possible to calculate. Also may be it will be possible to enum all visible controls, find all controls with grid headers and read header text from leftmost header. It will be left visible column header. What do you think? BTW, under Access 2010 scrollbar control windows class is "NUIScrollBar", not "ScrollBar" as it was in Access 2000

Answer (score 0):

No. You can determine from ColumnOrder the actual sequence of columns (visible or not) but not if a column is scrolled off the pane with visible columns.